# Find Maximum Value for a column in different sheets and report it in result sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I want to check `Column A` (*A1:A365*)  in `Sheet2`, `Sheet3`, `Sheet4` and `Sheet5` and find **Maximum** value for each cell. Compare `A1` in `Sheet2`, `Sheet3`, `Sheet4` and `Sheet5`, find maximum of it and report it in `A1` in result page. Also in cell `B1` report corresponding sheet for this maximum. This goes on to `Column A` (*A1:A365*)

[image]

the following code i used:

```
    Worksheets("sheet2").Range("A1").Value = a
    Worksheets("sheet3").Range("A1").Value = b
    Worksheets("sheet4").Range("A1").Value = c
    Worksheets("sheet5").Range("A1").Value = d
    MaxValue = Application.Max(a, b, c, d)
    Range("A1").Value = MaxValue
```

Comment: Sure. Can you show us what have you tried and where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: just Know these code to get Value

Worksheets("sheet2").Range("A1").Value = a
Worksheets("sheet3").Range("A1").Value = b
Worksheets("sheet4").Range("A1").Value = c
Worksheets("sheet5").Range("A1").Value = d
MaxValue = Application.Max(a, b, c, d)

Comment: Can you update your question with the code? It is really difficult reading code in comments.

Comment: Why do you need vba for this? A simple `=MAX(Sheet2!A1,Sheet3!A1,Sheet4!A1,Sheet5!A1)` formula in Cell A1 of Sheet1 will suffice? You can then copy the formula down?

Comment: yes but this is a part if bigger code
how can i find which sheet make this maximum,i want to have "sheet 2" for example

Comment: That can be also achieved using this horrifying formula... Oops! it's too long for the comment. Updating a screenshot

Comment: BTW are there always going to be 4 sheets? 2,3,4 and 5?

Comment: yes i have just 4 sheets

Comment: Ok one moment... posting a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> yes i have just 4 sheets – Mohsen 11 mins ago

**Non VBA Solution**

In Sheet1, Cell A1, put this formula

```
=MAX(Sheet2!A1,Sheet3!A1,Sheet4!A1,Sheet5!A1)
```

In Sheet1, Cell B1, put this horrifying formula. I am sure there is a better way to find the sheet name though.

`=IF(Sheet1!A1=Sheet2!A1,RIGHT(CELL("filename",Sheet2!A1),LEN(CELL("filename",Sheet2!A1))- FIND("]",CELL("filename",Sheet2!A1),1)),IF(Sheet1!A1=Sheet3!A1,RIGHT(CELL("filename",Sheet3!A1),LEN(CELL("filename",Sheet3!A1))- FIND("]",CELL("filename",Sheet3!A1),1)),IF(Sheet1!A1=Sheet4!A1,RIGHT(CELL("filename",Sheet4!A1),LEN(CELL("filename",Sheet4!A1))- FIND("]",CELL("filename",Sheet4!A1),1)),IF(Sheet1!A1=Sheet5!A1,RIGHT(CELL("filename",Sheet5!A1),LEN(CELL("filename",Sheet5!A1))- FIND("]",CELL("filename",Sheet5!A1),1)),""))))`

A word of **caution** though. To use the `RIGHT(CELL("filename",Sheet2!A1),LEN(CELL("filename",Sheet2!A1))- FIND("]",CELL("filename",Sheet2!A1),1))`, you need to have the workbook saved.

My Sheet2, A1 has `1`, Sheet3, A1 has `2`, Sheet4, A1 has `2.5`,Sheet5, A1 has `3`

[image]

**VBA Solution**

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    With ws
        .Range("A1:A365").Formula = "=MAX(Sheet2!A1,Sheet3!A1,Sheet4!A1,Sheet5!A1)"
        .Range("A1:A365").Value = .Range("A1:A365").Value
        For i = 1 To 365
            Select Case .Range("A" & i)

            Case ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & i).Value: .Range("B" & i).Value = "Sheet2"
            Case ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & i).Value: .Range("B" & i).Value = "Sheet3"
            Case ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A" & i).Value: .Range("B" & i).Value = "Sheet4"
            Case ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet5").Range("A" & i).Value: .Range("B" & i).Value = "Sheet5"

            End Select
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You should have waited before accepting an answer :) Someone just might come with a shorter formula to get the sheet name :)

Comment: plus one for the `horrifying formula` haha :)

Comment: @L42: Honestly, I am ashamed of it :) I am still trying to figure out a shorter formula. I am sure barry or lori might come up with a better formula.

Answer (score 2):

**Quick solution**

Based on Sidd's answer, here's my non-VBA solution without the *horrifying formula*:

1. Place this formula in Sheet1!A1: `=MAX(Sheet2:Sheet5!A1)`
2. As the sheet name does not have to be flexible (I'd assume you don't change it that often), you can use this formula in B1:

   ```
   =IF(Sheet2!A1=A1,"Sheet2",
   IF(Sheet3!A1=A1,"Sheet3",
   IF(Sheet4!A1=A1,"Sheet5",
   "Sheet5")))
   ```

**More structural solution** (better suited for many worksheets):

If you have many worksheets, you could consider this alternative.

1. Have a list of the relevant worksheets stored somewhere in your worksheet. (in the example, I place the list in E3:E7). Name this range `Sheets`. (Similar to Sidd's horrifying formula, I used the CELL formula to dynamically get each sheet name. However, this is not necessary in a static model)
2. (same as step 1 above): Place this formula in Sheet1!A1: `=MAX(Sheet2:Sheet5!A1)`
3. Place this formula in A2:

   `=INDEX(Sheets,MATCH(1,COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'"&Sheets&"'!A1"),A1),0))`

   Enter it as an array formula, i.e. press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

I uploaded the second solution [here](https://mega.co.nz/#!mR4WmCYJ!AvkwRVxLH0L2w6aTEj36TidIw6NEk0MYxkA3ARWy1cc).

Kudos to [this instruction](http://sites.madrocketscientist.com/jerrybeaucaires-excelassistant/search-functions/3d-lookup)!

Comment: + 1 For an alternative to the `horrifying` formula :p

Answer (score 1):

Since the formula is intended to be copied down, you don't want to hard-code a reference to cell `A1` in the `INDIRECT` in Peter Albert's formula. You can use `CELL("address",A1)` to get a reference to `A1` that can be copied down instead.

You can also avoid the need to array-enter the formula by using LOOKUP to return the result instead of `INDEX` & `MATCH`. 
Note that `LOOKUP` will return the name of the last worksheet with the max value in case of a tie.

The following formulas use a named range *Sheets* with the names of each worksheet

```
=MAX(Sheet2:Sheet5!A1)        returns max value (identical to Peter Albert's formula)
=LOOKUP(2,1/COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'" & Sheets & "'!" & CELL("address",A1)),A1),Sheets)      returns name of sheet with max value
```

Answer (score 0):

Make two new sheets with one titled "*First*" and the other "*Last*".  Make new sheets for your project originate through a button that contains a macro to add duplicate sheets between "*First* and *Last*".  Then just put one of these simple formulas for example in your reporting cell:  `=SUM(First:Last!K28)`  or  `=MAX(First:Last!K28)`